# How to change (assign) new value in FloatTensor, Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, assign

I am changing/assigning the value on the array(torch.cuda.floatTensor). I tried some way but it does not work. Please help me!

#1

```
#dis is [torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 3185x1 (GPU 0)]

s = dis.size(0) #3185
for i in range (0,s,1):
    if (dis[i,0] < 0):
        dis[i,0]== 0
#There is no error but It does not work.
```

#2

```
#dis is [torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 3185x1 (GPU 0)]

s = dis.size(0)
a = torch.zeros(s, 1).cuda()
idx = (dis > a)
dis[idx] = a[idx]

AssertionError: can't compare Variable and tensor
```

#3

```
#dis is [torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 3185x1 (GPU 0)]

s = dis.size(0)
a = torch.zeros(s, 1).cuda()
for i in range (0,s,1):
    if (dis[i,0] < a[i, 0]):
        dis[i,0]==a[i, 0]

#RuntimeError: bool value of Variable objects containing non-empty      torch.cuda.ByteTensor is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you need to replace values smaller than 0 with 0, Just use [torch.clamp](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.clamp), which is meant for such use cases:

```
dis = dis.clamp(min=0)
```

*Example*:

```py
import torch
dis = torch.tensor([[1], [-3], [0]])
#tensor([[ 1],
#        [-3],
#        [ 0]])

dis.clamp(min=0)
#tensor([[1],
#        [0],
#        [0]])
```

Comment: Thank you Psidom for you help! It works so well in my case. But in some cases, like replace  specific value to specific position. Can you show me how to do that? Thank you.
For example: like #3


s = dis.size(0)
a = torch.random(s, 1).cuda()
for i in range (0,s,1):
    if (dis[i,0] < a[i, 0]):
        dis[i,0]==a[i, 0]